# Distributed MINIO deployment duplicates server in pool

Tags: minio

I want to run minio cluster for tests, this cluster should contain 2 servers with 4 drives each.

For this purpose was selected minio setup as systemd service.

Both servers has same configuration in */etc/default/minio* file:

```html
# Volume to be used for MinIO server.
MINIO_VOLUMES="http://10.24.36.82/tmp/minio/srv/d{1...4} http://10.24.36.83/tmp/minio/srv/d{1...4}"
# Use if you want to run MinIO on a custom port.
#MINIO_OPTS="--address :9199"
# Root user for the server.
#MINIO_ROOT_USER=Root-User
# Root secret for the server.
```

Minio start is ok, cluster is working, but for some reason admin console shows that there're 3 servers in the cluster and one is always offine. When I open minio console on 10.24.36.82, it shows third server with same ip:
[image]

Server 10.24.36.83 has same picture but this time it has its own clone:
[image]

Lots of errors produced in minio logs about third server offline.

My question is why minio duplicates its instance and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in server url definition. MINIO_VOLUMES must contain port for every server pool address. If its not it starts somehow and tries to find extra server on port 80